# Are stainless steel studs acceptable as a feedpoint connector for an aluminum loop antenna?

Tags: antenna-construction

Similar to [Will stainless steel bolts work with my copper antenna?](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/10365/will-stainless-steel-bolts-work-with-my-copper-antenna) however my concern here is with electrical properties.

With copper antennas I never gave it much thought... just solder the wire.

I am finishing a loop antenna using aluminum tube and it seems to be a little tricky.  Easy enough is to use a steel or stainless steel stud for the feedline connection and crimp an appropriate terminal connector to the feedline wire.  Feedline will be something like 10-12 gage THHN going to a nearby auto-tuner.

Am I forgetting something important?

Not much concerned with galvanic corrosion as this is going in an attic.  But still avoiding direct copper-aluminum connection anyhow.

In case it matters, this is for HF and low VHF (80 meters - 6 meters) and power is expected to be limited to 100 watts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using stainless steel hardware to connect copper to aluminum works well as long as the copper and the aluminum are not allowed to be in contact. Home Depot carries some connectors designed to interface copper to aluminum in their electrical section.